# Plotting ROC curve from two different algorithms using lift in caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, ggplot2, r-caret

I have a two models like the following:

```
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)

library(caret)
set.seed(998)

my_data <- Sonar

fitControl <-
  trainControl(
    method = "boot632",
    number = 10,
    classProbs = T,
    savePredictions = "final",
    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary
  )


modelxgb <- train(
  Class ~ .,
  data = my_data,
  method = "xgbTree",
  trControl = fitControl,
  metric = "ROC"
)

library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)

library(caret)
set.seed(998)

my_data <- Sonar

fitControl <-
  trainControl(
    method = "boot632",
    number = 10,
    classProbs = T,
    savePredictions = "final",
    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary
  )


modelsvm <- train(
  Class ~ .,
  data = my_data,
  method = "svmLinear2",
  trControl = fitControl,
  metric = "ROC"
)
```

I want to plot the ROC curves for both models on one ggplot.

I am doing the following to generate the points for the curve:

```
for_lift_xgb = data.frame(Class = modelxgb$pred$obs,  xgbTree = modelxgb$pred$R)

for_lift_svm = data.frame(Class = modelsvm$pred$obs,  svmLinear2 = modelsvm$pred$R)

lift_obj_xgb = lift(Class ~ xgbTree, data = for_lift_xgb, class = "R")
lift_obj_svm = lift(Class ~ svmLinear2, data = for_lift_svm, class = "R")
```

What would be the easiest way to plot both of these curves on a single plot, and have them in different colors. I would also like to annotate the individual AUC values on the plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After building the models you can combine the predictions in a single data frame:

```
for_lift = data.frame(Class = modelxgb$pred$obs,
                      xgbTree = modelxgb$pred$R,
                      svmLinear2 = modelsvm$pred$R)
```

use it to build the lift object using the following:

```
lift = lift(Class ~ xgbTree + svmLinear2, data = for_lift, class = "R")
```

and plot with ggplot:

```
library(ggplot)

ggplot(lift$data)+
  geom_line(aes(1-Sp , Sn, color = liftModelVar))+
  scale_color_discrete(guide = guide_legend(title = "method"))
```

[image]

You can combine and compare many models this way.

To add auc to the plot you can create a data frame with the models names, the corresponding auc and the coordinates for plotting:

```
auc_ano <- data.frame(model = c("xgbTree","svmLinear2"),
                      auc = c(pROC::roc(response = for_lift$Class,
                                        predictor = for_lift$xgbTree,
                                        levels=c("M", "R"))$auc,
                              pROC::roc(response = for_lift$Class,
                                        predictor = for_lift$svmLinear2,
                                        levels=c("M", "R"))$auc),
                      y = c(0.95, 0.9))
auc_ano
#output
       model       auc    y
1    xgbTree 0.9000756 0.95
2 svmLinear2 0.5041086 0.90
```

and pass it to geom_text:

```
ggplot(lift$data)+
  geom_line(aes(1-Sp , Sn, color = liftModelVar))+
  scale_color_discrete(guide = guide_legend(title = "method"))+
  geom_text(data = auc_ano, aes(label = round(auc, 4), color = model, y = y), x = 0.1)
```

[image]